# Filter on single element transformed value of ArrayField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

Assuming I have the following Models defined:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db.models import Func, F


class SingleDayEvent(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    day = models.DateField()


class MultiDayEvent(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    days = ArrayField(models.DateField(), default=list)
```

If I want a queryset with all `SingleDayEvent` in a given calendar week, I would do:

```py
SingleDayEvent.objects.filter(day__week = week)
```

How can I achieve the same for the `MultiDayEvent` defined above given that the dates are stored in an ArrayField?

Comment: I have tried `MultiDayEvent.objects.annotate(single_days=Func(F('days'), function='unnest')).filter(single_days__week=week)` which doesn't work.

Comment: I know I can (almost) achieve what I need with the following `MultiDayEvent.objects.filter(days__overlap=[datetime.date.fromisocalendar(year=year, week=week, day=d)for d in range(1,8)])`. But this is not what I am looking for because now I need to specify the year, which is not necessary for the `SingleDayEvent`. And more importantly,  I am looking for a more general solution for filtering on transformed values of the `ArrayField` elements.